# Der Artikel der -nis Substantive

Tags: gender, suffix

Alle Substantive, die auf *-keit* enden, sind weiblich. Im Gegensatz können die auf *-nis* endenden Substantive sowohl weiblich als auch sächlich sein.

Warum ist das so? Warum sind einige dieser Substantive weiblich und andere sächlich? Gibt es überhaupt eine Erklärung?

Comment: "Das ist halt so..." gilt nicht als Erklärung, oder? ^_^

Comment: Ich bin die [Liste der auf -nis endenden Wörter im Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thesaurus:-nis) durchgegangen und habe nach Regeln oder Regelmäßigkeiten gesucht. Spätestens nach drei Zeilen wurde jeder Regelversuch widerlegt. Keine Chance. Siehe auch auf [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/nis.html).

Comment: Was "heit" angeht. Das war ganz früher mal ein selbstständiges Wort und es war maskulin und bedeutete sowas wie "Wesen". Dann fingen die Leute langsam an, es als Suffix zu benutzen und je nach Germanischem Dialekt gab es mehr oder weniger Einfluss auf das Geschlecht des Ergebnisses. Im Altsächsischen zum Beispiel gab es noch maskuline "-heit"-Wörter. Feminin setzte sich aber rasch durch, wohl unter anderem da ein Großteil der so gebildeten Wörter personifizierte Abstrakta sind, die wohl tendenziell feminin waren. Quelle des ganzen:... Grimms Wörterbuch

Comment: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Gliederung&lemid=GH05708#XGH05708

Comment: @Jan Es fällt auf, dass für fast jedes dort aufgeführte feminine Substantiv auf _-nis_ ein sehr ähnliches auf _-heit_ existiert, für fast alle im Neutrum hingegen nicht.

Comment: @Crissov Die Empfängtheit? Die Erkenntheit? Leider lässt sich so auch keine Regel konstruieren =C

Comment: @Emanuel: ich habe nicht viele Wörter geprüft (~10), aber es scheint so, dass sehr viele -nis Abstrakten sind tatsächlich feminin und die nicht Abstrakten - sächlich.

Answer (score 5):

Ich kenne dazu keine Regel. Ich weiß nur, dass die weiblichen -nis-Wörter zur Flexionsklasse »*-/e*« und die sächlichen zur Flexionsklasse »*(e)s/e*« gehören. Da hilft aber nicht, das Geschlecht zu bestimmen. Es hilft höchstens den Genitiv zu bilden wenn man das Geschlecht schon kennt.

Prinzipiell ist es im Deutschen so, dass man, wenn man ein Nomen lernt, immer auch sofort das Geschlecht mitlernen muss. Es gibt zwar ein paar Regeln, die helfen das Geschlecht zu finden, aber es gibt deutlich mehr Wörter, auf die man keine dieser Regeln anwenden kann, als Wörter bei denen man mit einer Regel ans Ziel kommt.

Man muss also das machen, was auch Kleinkinder machen, die Deutsch als Muttersprache lernen: Das Geschlecht immer gleich mit dem Wort mitlernen.

Wichtig ist auch sich vor Augen zu halten, dass es nicht der Gegenstand ist, der ein grammatikalisches Geschlecht hat, sondern das Wort mit dem der Gegenstand bezeichnet wird. »Auto«, »Wagen« und »Limousine« können Bezeichnungen für ein und denselben Gegenstand sein, dennoch ist *das Auto* sächlich, *der Wagen* männlich und *die Limousine* weiblich. (Aus demselben Grund ist es auch möglich, dass *das Mädchen* grammatikalisch sächlich ist, obwohl es biologisch natürlich weiblich ist.)

---

Noch eine Ergänzung zu den beiden oben erwähnten Flexionsklassen: Sie unterscheiden sich nur im Genitiv Singular:

**weiblich *-/e***

> Nominativ: **Die Besorgnis** war der Mutter deutlich anzusehen.
>   Genitiv: Lisas Leichtsinn war die Ursache **ihrer Besorgnis**.

**sächlich *(e)s/e***

> Nominativ: **Das Hindernis** war gestern noch nicht hier.
>   Genitiv: Ich kenne den Verursacher **des Hindernisses**.